# Send ajax requests without cookies in the same domain?

Tags: ajax, http, jquery, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I see that google or twitter autosuggest's sends ajax requests which are very lightweight since they don't send any cookies with the request. I was wondering how do they do it?
I googled about ways but i found ways like sending via CORS but they are sending the request to the same domain.

Any idea or ways on how to do that.
I am using chrome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

These are the two options I can think of to answer your question:

**Option 1:** Set `withCredentials: false` when using XMLHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

**Option 2:** Delete cookies before sending the request and (in the case of wanted re-use restore them afterwards from temp variable) like so:

1. Get cookies and store them somewhere (f.i. in global var)
2. Delete cookies from domain
3. Send AJAX request
4. Restore cookies from variable